# Change navbar color while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Just did that way with pure javascript to change navbar color after scrolling,
it worked with google chrome without any problem
but when I tried to test it at firefox
it's not working with it.

Anyone can give me any advice about this ?
Thanks in advance.

```js
var myNav = document.getElementById("nav");

window.onscroll = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 280) {
        myNav.classList.add("scroll");
    } else {
        myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
    }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:4000px;
  }
.nav {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#111;
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
.scroll {
  background-color:transparent;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav" class="nav"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you are using pure javascript*:

Firefox and IE has the overflow at `html` while Chrome, Safari and Opera places it at the `body` level:

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp) for more info:

> var body = document.body; // For Chrome, Safari and Opera
>
> var html = document.documentElement; // Firefox and IE places the overflow at the
>    level, unless else is specified. Therefore, we use the
>   documentElement property for these two browsers

So you must use this:

```
if (document.body.scrollTop >= 280 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 280) {
```

and it will work cross-browser. Cheers!

```js
var myNav = document.getElementById("nav");

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 280 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 280) {
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else {
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 4000px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.scroll {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav" class="nav"></div>
```

*If you are using jquery*:

```js
var myNav = $("#nav");

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 280) {
    myNav.addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    myNav.removeClass("scroll");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 4000px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.scroll {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav" class="nav"></div>
```

Comment: @YahyaEssam see the pure javascript and jquery options here... Thanks!

Comment: this is very new information for me about the browsers overflow . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20){  
  $('#navBar').css({property: "value"});
    } else {
        $('#navBar').css({property: "value"});
    }
});
```

Not really an answer, but this works great for me in all browsers that I've tested on (ie, edge, safari, chrome & firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Change the "280" to how many px down you want to scroll before the navbar background color changes to transparent.

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
        //background on scroll
        $("#navbar").addClass("scroll");
    } else {
        //background at top
       $("#navbar").removeClass("scroll");
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
background-color:#111;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.scroll {
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: worked with me thank you , however I was looking for pure javascript code not JQuery.

Comment: Sorry about that! kukkuz has a working pure JS implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39802504/4411240